# An empty data frame error when using read_excel(),skiprow

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel with an explanation written in the first row as follows:
I want to convert the second row as a header and the data below it into a dataframe format.
So I wrote the following code, but the result is an empty data frame

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=1)
```

```
print(df) =
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

If I enter Excel and delete the first row and do not use `skiprows`, a correct dataframe appears. Which should I fix?
[image]

And since there is only one sheet, I did not set it

When opening the first file saved, the cursor is positioned at row=1 column[a]=1. If I change the cursor position and save the excel, the data frame comes out well. How do I move the cursor and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skiprows=1 works fine me.

```
pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx', skiprows=1)
```

Here is an alternative using openpyxl, maybe you can give this a try and see -

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data = []
for row in ws.values:
    data.append([item for item in row])
df = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[1])
```

Comment: The first method failed, but the second method succeeded. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

have you tried skiprows=[0]?
This is outlined here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Then the default behaviour for headers should be taken as the new row 0

Comment: I tried it the way I said, but I got an empty data frame

Comment: In my opinion, the data frame seems to read 1 row because A, B, C of 1 row are merged. So it seems that there is no data when I skiprows

Comment: without using skiprows, if you do a describe() on the dataframe, what is the result.
since you also are not uploading your data, can you send an image of the resulting df without skiprows?

Comment: ```df = pd.read_excel(filename)
print(df) = Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1.excelexplanation... 
2....
3...    ]
Index: []```

Comment: It seems that only the first row of excel is being read. The rest of the rows are not visible

Comment: i recreated your excel file and ran my code, it works fine even without skiprows.
what version of python are you using?

Comment: i use python3.9

Comment: i'm not sure how to help. with 3.8.1 it works. i thought maybe your merged cells were causing some issue, but like i said, i recreated exactly your workbook.
Try remove that line and see what happens. Sorry.

Comment: When opening the first file saved, the cursor is positioned at row=1 column[a]=1. If I change the cursor position and save the excel, the data frame comes out well. How do I move the cursor and save it?

Comment: interesting - i tried both and both work ok. maybe your file just wasnt read properly.

Comment: please accept answer if original answer worked

Answer (score 0):

The skiprow argument looks at rows starting from 0. So you have to put `skiprows=0`.

Comment: When I tried what I said, only the line with the description of excel is printed.(
First row in excel)

Comment: In my opinion, the data frame seems to read 1 row because A, B, C of 1 row are merged. So it seems that there is no data when I skiprows